# Bind dropdown list of another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, knockout.js

I will start my question by describing desired outcome:

I want to build an input form to post to my API using knockout JS, however the Entity object I want to input has foreign keys so I need to give a select option for all of the options in the foreign table.

#### Lessons View Model

```
var lessonRegisterViewModel;

function Lesson(id, name, teacher, room, subject, startTime, endTime) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(id);
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.Teacher = ko.observable(teacher);
    self.Room = ko.observable(room);
    self.Subject = ko.observable(subject);
    self.StartTime = ko.observable(startTime);
    self.EndTime = ko.observable(endTime);
    self.addLesson = function() {
        var dataObject = ko.toJSON(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Lessons',
            type: 'post',
            data: dataObject,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                lessonRegisterViewModel.lessonListViewModel.lessons.push(new Lesson(data.Id, data.Name, data.Teacher, data.Room, data.Subject, data.StartTime, data.EndTime));
                self.Id(null);
                self.Name('');
                self.Teacher('');
                self.Room('');
                self.Subject('');
                self.StartTime('');
                self.EndTime('');
            }
        });
    }
}

function LessonList() {
    var self = this;
    self.lessons = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.getLessons = function() {
        self.lessons.removeAll();
        $.getJSON('/api/Lessons', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                self.lessons.push(new Lesson(value.id, value.name, value.teacher, value.room, value.subject, value.startTime, value.endTime));
                console.log(self);
            });
        });
    };
    self.removeLesson = function(lesson) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Lessons/' + lesson.Id(),
            type: 'delete',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function() {
                self.lessons.remove(lesson);
            }
        });
    }
}
lessonRegisterViewModel = {
    addLessonViewModel: new Lesson(),
    lessonListViewModel: new LessonList()
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind view model to referring view
    ko.applyBindings(lessonRegisterViewModel);
    // load lesson data
    lessonRegisterViewModel.lessonListViewModel.getLessons();
});
```

#### Example JSON we get out:

```
[  
 {  
  "id":1,
  "name":"Lesson 1",
  "teacher":{  
     "id":3,
     "firstName":"Sophie",
     "lastName":"Adams",
     "emailAddress":"teacher3@foo.com"
  },
  "classroom":{  
     "id":1,
     "name":"Great Hall"
  },
  "subject":{  
     "id":4,
     "name":"jQuery"
  },
  "startTime":"2016-02-10T09:30:00",
  "endTime":"2016-02-10T10:30:00"
},
{  
  "id":2,
  "name":"Lesson 2",
  "teacher":{  
     "id":4,
     "firstName":"Tristan",
     "lastName":"Sanchez",
     "emailAddress":"teacher4@foo.com"
  },
  "classroom":{  
     "id":2,
     "name":"Room 1A"
  },
  "subject":{  
     "id":3,
     "name":"SQL"
  },
   "startTime":"2016-02-10T09:00:00",
  "endTime":"2016-02-10T10:30:00"
}
]
```

So essentially I am inserting a lesson, which comprises of

Name
Teacher
Room
Subject
StartTime
EndTime

I need to go off, and offer dropdown lists for all the teachers in the database, I also need to do this for rooms and subjects. I have working View Models for each of the individual entities with no dependencies, so I can physically complete all CRUD on Teachers, Rooms and Subjects.

Any suggestions on how to implement this would be welcomed.

Comment: You will need an array (possibly observable) for each of the things you want to have a dropdown of. So a list of all the Teachers, a list of all the Rooms, a list of all the Subjects. Can you get that?

Comment: @RoyJ how do I go about building it into that view model?

Comment: `lessonRegisterViewModel.teachers: ko.observableArray()` seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a "I can't make it do what I want" kind of issue, but more of a mental block about where things fit into your model. So let me suggest a different mental approach.

What you have built is a thorough data model of your primary data object. But your **goal** is to build is an application, which will need that data model, but also other things, all in its viewmodel.

A viewmodel is specified *entirely* by a view: you need to implement exactly the set of things that your view will use. So start by writing the HTML with its data bindings. If your application is going to have a `<select>` item that needs a list of rooms, just go ahead and assume such a member exists in your view model and make the binding.

Once you have laid out the application this way, you have fully specified your viewmodel. You've created an interface (all the viewmodel members) that you need to implement. The application — not the data — defines the viewmodel. So start with the application and leave the data modeling to the implementation phase.